# Firebase deploy error: Cannot find module '@slack/web-api'

Tags: firebase, slack-api

I'm following the [Fireship tutorial](https://fireship.io/lessons/how-to-build-a-slack-bot/) to create a Slack bot using Firebase.

When I run `firebase deploy`, I get the following error:

```
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '@slack/web-api'
```

I can confirm that I have successfully installed the library.

```
% npm install @slack/web-api

up to date, audited 179 packages in 760ms
```

Here's the code that references the Slack API:

```
import { WebClient } from '@slack/web-api';
const slackClient = new WebClient(functions.config().slack.token);
```

Full error from running `firebase deploy`:

```
% firebase deploy           

=== Deploying to 'synergy-slack-bot'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> functions@ build /Users/nick-home/Projects/synergy-slack-bot/functions
> tsc

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loading and anaylzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
Serving at port 8444

shutdown requested via /__/quitquitquit

i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /Users/nick-home/Projects/synergy-slack-bot/functions (55.74 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 18 (1st Gen) function bot(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 18 (1st Gen) function slackChannelJoin(us-central1)...
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Provided module can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '@slack/web-api'
Require stack:
- /workspace/lib/index.js
- /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/loader.js
- /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/main.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/lib/index.js:15:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
Could not load the function, shutting down.. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Provided module can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '@slack/web-api'
Require stack:
- /workspace/lib/index.js
- /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/loader.js
- /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/main.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/lib/index.js:15:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
Could not load the function, shutting down.. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        bot(us-central1)
        slackChannelJoin(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
Error: There was an error deploying functions:
- Error Failed to update function bot in region us-central1
- Error Failed to update function slackChannelJoin in region us-central1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that the tutorial didn't mention: Turns out you need to `cd` into the `functions` folder, and then run the `npm` commands. I was running the `npm` command from the parent folder. Seems obvious in hindsight, as the generated `functions` folder is where the NPM config is.